# Twentyten theme header Image not changing by using the child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, header, twenty-ten-theme

I am using the **Twentyten theme** of **Version: 2.0**. I want to use this theme for my blog site, I am developing my blog site using the child theme. This theme has the header image feature that is flexible when the page or single post is shown.

I mean in the page the header image is of the page featured image. And when I am in the single post then it has the post featured image. Then in the index.php it has the default image. Now my question is that what I am doing wrong in the below codes in the child theme functions.php file.

```
function twentyten_setup_another() {
    $custom_header_supportp = array(
        'width' => apply_filters( 'twentyten_header_image_width', 980 ),
        'height' => apply_filters( 'twentyten_header_image_height', 224 ),
    );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'twentyten_setup_another' );
```

that is not showing the above functionality in the header image sections. I mean the **header image flexibility** has been removed when I put those codes in the child theme functions.php.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return` or `echo` something, whenever you use action hooks:

```
function twentyten_setup_another() {
    $custom_header_supportp = array(
        'width' => apply_filters( 'twentyten_header_image_width', 980 ),
        'height' => apply_filters( 'twentyten_header_image_height', 224 ),
    );

    return $custom_header_supportp;
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'twentyten_setup_another' );
```

Comment: Actually the default in the parent theme was 940px width and 198px, I want width and height to be 980px and 224px respectively. That must be achieved with the header image functionality that will be different in the different page or in single post. You code is working for the header image flixlible functionality but it does not increase the width and the height. How can I achieve this. Please help me.